# modify a python list from C++

Tags: c++, python, ctypes

I got a Python list which I can obtain its pointer and pass this pointer address to C++ to work on

```
MyPointer = TheList.as_pointer()
```

now I pass this address to C++ with ctypes

in C++ I can do the following:

```
*(float*) MyPointer = 2.0f; //for example
```

and the Python values will update immediatly,now the problem is:
how to extend or delete some values (like modify the list directly from C++)
as I sense these data are a `std::vector` how to do `push_back` and so on to adjust size with a fast way (as iterating in Python is pretty much SLOW)

Comment: `as_pointer` seems to be Blender specific as far as I can see … Anyway, a Python `list` is *not* implemented as a `std::vector`, it’s an own data structure. You need to cast your pointer to that data type to work with it. The type is defined in the [Python C API](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/).

Comment: You are better off actually writing a C extension module than using ctypes when you want to use the Python C-API, see http://docs.python.org/2.7/extending/index.html and http://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/list.html

Comment: @KonradRudolph true it is from Blender Python api :)

Comment: If you need fast iteration, you probably want to work with `array.array('d')` or with `numpy.array` anyway. They allow efficient packing of floating-point numbers into the array. A Python list, on the other hand, contains (in C++ terminology) pointers to stack-allocated objects, each of which contains a single double. I.e. it's like an `std::vector<PyObject*>`, where each `PyObject*` must be dereferenced to get to the underlying `double`. To append to a single number to a Python list, you must heap-allocate it to get the `PyObject*`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given only that pointer, you cannot extend the list. What you are passing to C++ is the address of the *array* internally used to implement the Python list. This cannot be an `std::vector`, as Python lists are not implemented as STL vectors, but as C-level arrays of Python object references. These arrays do not contain a backpointer to the Python list object.

To mutate the list, take a look at [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/) and link your C++ code with the Python library. If you really must call your C++ function from ctypes, call it with the `id` of the list to get the pointer to the list, as opposed to its element array. Then you can operate on the list like this:

```c
#include <Python.h>

extern "C"
void append_to_list(uintptr_t lst_id)
{
    PyObject* lst = reinterpret_cast<PyObject*>(ptr);
    PyObject* new_num = PyFloat_FromDouble(2.0);
    if (!new_num) {
        ... PyFloat creation failed ...
    }
    int ret = PyList_Append(lst, new_num);
    Py_DECREF(new_num);
    if (ret) {
        ... PyList_Append failed ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand the concept but it gives me when excuting in python a memory error : access violation reading at 0x000

Comment: it is failing at PyList_Append

Comment: didn't put error checking,but did printf after each line and it didn't print after the PyList_Append

Comment: well i didn't check the values (but i know if errors will generate -1 from python documentations)

as I found a better way to work without PyObjects (I hate them :D)
I casted to a float pointer and worked with it ^_^ still will try to modify its size (don't know how yet)